# ValueError: Too many elements provided. Needed at most -761894396, but received 1

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, keras

When trying to fit a fairly simple convolutional + dense layer model in keras I can't seem to get it to complete the fit() function.

the x training data is a numpy array of shape i_train.shape(10,1070,1230,3) in (batchsize,height,width,channels) format.
the y training data is of shape m_train.shape(10,1070,1230) in (batchsize, height, width) format.

```
nb_filter = 1
nb_row = 3
nb_col = 3

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(nb_filter, (nb_row, nb_col), padding = 'same', 
activation='relu', input_shape=(h,w,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(h*w, activation='relu', input_shape= (329025,)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Reshape((h,w)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(i_train, m_train, batch_size=10, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-639284a1176d>", line 1, in <module>
    model.fit(i_train, m_train, batch_size=10, epochs=10, verbose=1)

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 870, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1490, in fit
    self._make_train_function()

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1014, in _make_train_function
    self.total_loss)

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 162, in get_updates
    moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 162, in <listcomp>
    moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 601, in zeros
    return variable(tf.constant_initializer(0., dtype=tf_dtype)(shape),

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py", line 162, in __call__
    verify_shape=self.verify_shape)

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))

  File "C:\Users\Jacob.Rose\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\TFlow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 424, in make_tensor_proto
    (shape_size, nparray.size))

ValueError: Too many elements provided. Needed at most -761894396, but received 1
```

Comment: Weird. That looks like 32-bit signed overflow.

Comment: It is an overflow indeed. Either you have layers with way too many filters/units, or your data is too much. I had that problem, and the only thing I could do was to try smaller things.

Comment: Did you fix it now?

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm no longer working on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The summary of your model: 
[image]

So that the number of params for your dense_1 (excluded bias): 329025 * 1316100 = 433029802500. It's too many params for a layer.
You should add more Conv2D and Pooling layers to reduce size of image and reduce the output size of Dense layer.